# Take JSON from a file, add a key to it. And then overwrite the file with the key in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hello Stack Overflow Users/Developers,

I'm trying to take **JSON** from a file using the *fs* module, add a key to the variable that holds the **JSON**, and then overwrite the file. Basically making a Data Saving System with *fs*. I've tried many different ways but I came across an error when trying this.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected End of JSON input`

```js
var UserTable = JSON.stringify(require('./data/Data'))
    UserTable[`User_${id[key]}`] = value;

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(UserTable);
    }, 1000);

    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/data/Data.json', UserTable);
```

Comment: where are you getting the error? and please paste the json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your are updating json after JSON.stringfy().

Before abc.json file

---

```
{
   name : "Tom"
}
```

---

```
const appjson = require("./abc.json");
var fs = require('fs');

id = [1, 2, 3, 4] // json or array
key = 3 //index or key
value = "some_value" // data to set

appjson[`User_${id[key]}`] = value;

fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/abc.json', JSON.stringify(appjson));
```

---

After abc.json

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "User_4": "some_value"
}
```